# How to in salt find host when specific package installed

Tags: salt-stack

I have hundreds of servers connected to the salt-master. 
I need to find all servers when specific package installed or service is running.
How I can write a query (minion target) to find these minions and run a single command (service restart for example).

Answer (score 0):

### Ad-hoc Commands Against Target Minions

First, find the best way to target your minions by referencing the [Targeting Minions](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/) Salt documentation, or the [Getting Started: Targeting](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/getstarted/fundamentals/targeting.html) guide.

For example, if it is checking all minions running CentOS, you could just target with a query focused on the `os` grain:

```
salt -G 'os:centos' test.ping
```

If you wanted each one of them that had the `vim-enhanced` package installed, modify the query with the [pkg execution module](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/master/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.pkg.html):

```
salt -G 'os:centos' pkg.version vim-enhanced
```

Then you can use a simple bash script to loop through the results with the command you want to run after, but use the `--out txt` argument to simplify the output for use in a bash script.

A simple bash script example that uses the [service execution module](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.service.html):

```sh
PKG_INSTALLED=`salt -G 'os:centos' pkg.version vim-enhanced --out txt | cut -d':' -f1`
for PKG in "$PKG_INSTALLED"; do
  salt "$PKG" service.start <target-service>
done
```

This can be simplified further with the `-L` argument:

```
TARGETS=`salt -G 'os:centos' pkg.version vim-enhanced --out txt | cut -d':' -f1`
salt -L "$TARGETS" service.start <service>
```

Info on the `-L` arg:

```
-L, --list    Instead of using shell globs to evaluate the target
              servers, take a comma or whitespace delimited list 
              of servers.
```

That command can technically be reduced down to a one-liner, but it is a long one:

```
salt -L "$(salt -G 'os:centos' pkg.version vim-enhanced --out txt | cut -d':' -f1)" service.start <service>
```

### Using Salt States

If not wanting merely ad-hoc targeting, it would be advisable to use [Salt States](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/master/topics/tutorials/starting_states.html).

### Resources

The following should be good resources:

- [Getting Started: Fundamentals](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/getstarted/fundamentals/index.html): This includes targeting, basic states, and applying states to targets.
- [Getting Started: Configuration Management](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/getstarted/config/index.html): This includes more in-depth information, including a deeper look at states.

Comment: Thank you @ScriptAutomate. Your answer is regular way and well known way. I ask if exists some targeting that can do it in one command without writing scripts.

Comment: I've updated the commands needed down to two lines (and a one-liner version), rather than using a bash loop.  For the kind of targeting you were asking about, being minions with a specific package installed or service running, I think you are required to create your list from a query first before a follow-up command executes something against them. For a potentially better answer, you can revise your question to lay out what you had tried, what alternative solutions you were aware of (that you feel are well known or too long), and a specific example to work from, as these were not provided.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I success to write one-line command, but I can't call my solution beautiful, because I use some pillar values to select minions. Now I clearly understand that solution I'm looking for just doesn't exists.